# Integral relationship problem

Tags: calculus, integration

I have the following problem:

If $f$ is continuous and $\int_0^9 f(x)dx = 9$ find $\int_0^3 xf(x^2)dx$

I am not sure how to do this, Would it have to do with the limits of integration and chain rule?

Here is my best (and incorrect) guess.

$$\int_0^{x^2} f(t) dt = xf(x^2)dx + C$$

I do not know where to go from here...

Any help or hints would be appreciated... thanks.

Comment: Make the change of variable $u=x^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set $x =t^2$ then $dx=2tdt$ so $$\int\limits_0^9f(x)dx=\int\limits_0^3f(t^2)(2t)dt=2\int\limits_0^3tf(t^2)dt=9$$ so it follows that $$\int\limits_0^3xf(x^2)dx=\frac{9}{2}.$$

Comment: Thank you. I got it figured out

Answer (score 3):

By change of variable $x=t^2$ so $dx=2tdt$ we have

$$\int_0^9f(x)dx=2\int_0^3tf(t^2)dt=9$$
so the desired value of the integral is $\frac 9 2$.